# How to disable TFS workitem link funcationality when the workitem is in Removed state?

Tags: tfs

For example, if there is a Product Backlog Item in Removed State, how can I prevent team to add tasks or test cases to it?

I originally thought of setting the workitem as FROZEN. But it might not work if we need to be able to reactivate the PBI when requirement changes.

Answer (score 0):

Education.

You need to train your users in use of the system so that they don't make amateur mistakes like that.

There is no way in the tool to prevent links based on state.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for @MrHinsh's answer by default.

I haven't tried this myself as yet, but I *think* it should work... I'll delete the answer if it doesn't.

To make a work item read only for most people, while still allowing selected users to edit it you can put the work item into a situation where the validation rules fail for most but succeed for the selected users. That way, people can make the changes but can't save them.

For example, add a field such as the following:

```
<FIELD name="ReadOnly" refname="My.ReadOnlyFlag" type="String">
  <WHENNOTCHANGED FIELD="System.State">
    <PROHIBITEDVALUES expanditems="true" for="[Project]\Contributors"> 
      <LISTITEM value="true" /> 
    </PROHIBITEDVALUES> 
    <HELPTEXT>The work item is now locked. No changes can be saved</HELPTEXT> 
  </WHENNOTCHANGED>
</FIELD>
```

Then in the transitions to the `Removed` state, set the `My.ReadOnlyFlag` value to `true`.

See how you go with that approach and whether it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, Richard! I will give it a try but just wondering how would adding a readonly field prevents users from adding links to workitem?